# how to remove margin or padding of window in javascript/css?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to print image using `javascript` :

```
function printImage(src){
        var printWindow = window.open('', 'Print Window','height=400,width=600');
        printWindow.document.write('<html><head><title>Print Window</title>');
        printWindow.document.write('</head><body ><img src=\'');
        printWindow.document.write(src);
        printWindow.document.write('\' /></body></html>');
        printWindow.document.close();
        printWindow.print();
}

printImage(src); //this is image src..
```

It prints fine the problem is here :

[image]

I want to remove that **empty space** because I'm printing it on narrow paper(bill/receipt paper). Image is prints very small think because of that **empty spaces**. I've tried like set `style="margin-top:-25px; margin-left: -25px;"` on `img` but its prints like :

[image]

How can I print the `image` on `left top` without any empty space?

Help me..
Thank you..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try css `@page`

```
@page {
    size: auto;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: can I set it from JS ?

Comment: This helped me remove the empty space after the print header!